# How to extract css to file from vue-cli webpack-simple project?

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm still learning Vue, so I'm struggling to figure out how to convert the inline css to a css file.

If anyone could help me out setting up the css(scss) extraction to a single css file, I would be grateful!

Or will that defeat the purpose of vue's scoped styles?

Here's my webpack.config code:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }    
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'

  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `npm run build` yet? I have a `vue-cli` Webpack project and `npm run build` automatically pulls the CSS out of my `.vue` files and into a separate `.css` file. Also, by "inline CSS", are you referring to CSS in the `<style>` section of your `.vue` files? Or are you referring to CSS that is defined in `style=""` attributes in the `<template>` sections of your `.vue` files?

Comment: I think the webpack-simple cli doesnt have the extraction built in. It writes the css in the header of the file, not inline ofc.

Comment: Ok, then it seems like one quick solution might be to create a 'full' Webpack project and move your code into it. I find the Webpack config and build files very difficult to understand, and it could take you a long time to figure out how to set things up manually to replicate the behavior of a full Webpack project.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Gonna try that out. 
Thanks Nathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to sum up our comments:

The answer here was for him to create a new 'full' Webpack project and move his code into it.

**Reasons:**

1. A full webpack project pulls out CSS from `.vue` files automatically into a single CSS file, which is what he wants.
2. "[T]he webpack-simple cli doesnt have [CSS] extraction built in".
3. The webpack config and build files can be very difficult to understand, and it could take him a long time to figure out how to set things up manually to replicate the behavior of a full Webpack project.

Comment: Hey Nathan, I got the vue-cli webpack up and running, and I figured out how to change my files so I can run it in the full webpack cli. Cheers for all the help man! 

One question: is there an easy way to run the build from a subdirectory instead of the root?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I have my webpack project in a folder named `client`. Normally I open a terminal, `cd` into the `client` folder, and then run `npm run build` from within `client`. However, if I `cd` into a subdirectory of `client`, say `client/config`, `npm run build` will still work. So I can "run the build from a subdirectory instead of the root [of the project]". But maybe you mean something different?

Comment: I mean, that I want to upload the build to a subdirectory on my webserver, and not run it from the root. I have uploaded it to http://woolff.dk/frontio/ but when I run it in the browser, the window is blank.

Comment: What are you using to serve webpages / static assets? For example, I'm using a Flask server (Python) to serve the app.html which contains my Vue app and its associated static files (JavaScript and CSS).

Comment: You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954174/4115031) in which I describe exactly how I got my Vue.js project working with my Flask web server.